# How to Sign in with Apple in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to implement singing in with Apple in my Jetpack Compose app, through Firebase. I have already setup everything in Firebase etc. since I also use the same firebase server to let users Sign in with Apple in the corresponding iOS app. (Services ID, Apple Team ID, Key ID, Private Key and auth URL)

Here is my code for singing in:

```
class ContinueWithApple(
    private val context: Context,
    private val appLanguage: String,
    private val isSigningIn: MutableState<Boolean>
): Register()  {

    fun singIn() {

        isSigningIn.value = true

        userIsAlreadySigningIn(auth, isSigningIn) {

            if (!it) {

                singInUser(
                    auth = auth,
                    context = context,
                    appLanguage = appLanguage,
                    isSigningIn = isSigningIn
                ) {

                }

            } //: END IF

        } //: USER IS ALREADY SIGNING IN

    } //: FUN

} //: CLASS

fun userIsAlreadySigningIn(
    auth: FirebaseAuth,
    isSigningIn: MutableState<Boolean>,
    completion: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    val pending = auth.pendingAuthResult

    if (pending != null) {

        pending

            .addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->

                Log.d("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "checkPending:onSuccess:$authResult")
                isSigningIn.value = false
                completion(true)

            } //: ON SUCCESS

            .addOnFailureListener { e ->

                Log.w("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "checkPending:onFailure", e)
                isSigningIn.value = false
                completion(true)

            } //: ON FAILURE

    } else {

        Log.d("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "pending: null")
        completion(false)

    } //: END IF

} //: FUN

fun singInUser(
    auth: FirebaseAuth,
    context: Context,
    appLanguage: String,
    isSigningIn: MutableState<Boolean>,
    completion: (FirebaseUser?) -> Unit
) {

    val provider = OAuthProvider
        .newBuilder("apple.com")
        .setScopes(mutableListOf("email", "name"))
        .addCustomParameter("locale", HelperFunctions.currentLanguageLocale(appLanguage))
        .build()

    auth
        .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(context.getActivity(), provider)
        .addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->

            Log.d("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "activitySignIn:onSuccess:${authResult.user}")
            completion(authResult.user)

        } //: ON SUCCESS

        .addOnFailureListener { e ->

            Log.w("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "activitySignIn:onFailure", e)
            isSigningIn.value = false
            completion(null)

        } //: ON FAILURE

} //: FUN
```

When the user presses the button to sing in, a google chrome tab appears, but this error is visible:

> {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from this Android client application  are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED","domain":"googleapis.com","metadata":{"service":"identitytoolkit.googleapis.com","consumer":"projects/952288320256"}}]}}

Any ideas what might be the problem?

P.S. This is how I get the Activity:

```
internal fun Context.getActivity(): Activity {
    var context = this
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is Activity) return context
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    throw IllegalStateException("Permissions should be called in the context of an Activity")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/proto-google-common-protos/latest/com.google.api.ErrorReason), you can see that the error you are getting is because:

> The request is denied because it violates API key Android application
> restrictions.

If you look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_application_restrictions), it will show you the steps you need to take in order to not receive this error.

I would verify that you have followed all the steps correctly.

Double check that your google-service.json file is correct and that you have added your signed APK SHA-1 as well.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem is that my API key is restricted to only Android Apps. However, in order to Sign in with Apple, you have to sign in through their website. Do you maybe happen to know how to set my API restriction to only websites and android apps? I can either set it to one restriction, or to none, which I do not want.

Comment: @IraklisEleftheriadis - Glad you found your problem. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such, so other people can find it easier. If you have a different question, I can recommend to ask a new one.